# Pandas date comparison giving Invalid type comparison error

Tags: pandas

I have a column in a dataframe of type datetime64[ns]. I am trying to compare it to  a date constant like below:

```
df_new=df_old[df_old['date_col'] > pd.to_datetime('2018-11-01')]
```

I get:

```
invalid type comparison
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Show us some sample data ?

Comment: Might be useful to get `df_new.dtypes` my spidey sense says `df_old['date_col']` isn't really a date.

Comment: as suggested your df column is probably not datetime: `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-10'))` then do `df[df[0] > pd.to_datetime('2018-01-04')]` and it works as expected.